# PubNub subscribe android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pubnub

I am trying to setup listener in pubnub in an android app but am having problems. The app crashes whenever any message is received. I am getting this error in logcat - `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Can anyone suggest any solution to this?

Comment: Which version of PubNub Android SDK? Can you share more complete code?

Comment: It is solved now. I found that I couldn’t modify or do anything to the textview from insider the subscribe listener, so I made a new asynctask

Comment: You can also use runOnUiThread

Comment: You should post as official answer ^^^

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer on behalf of Ayush Singh

I found that I couldn’t modify or do anything to the textview from inside the subscribe listener, so I made a new async task.

You can also use `runOnUiThread`.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens always when you try updating **UI View** out of the main thread which created this view, so you should put your updating code inside  *runOnUiThread* method. And here is the simplest way to do that in kotlin using lambda.

```
runOnUiThread {         
     Log.i("Tag", "runOnUiThread") 
     // put your code here
}
```